# ubuntu, php 7.4 and module rdkafka doesnt work because of compiled module version mismatch

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache-kafka

I installed PHP 7.4 and RdKafka by using PECL however the module didn't start, here is the output of php -v

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: rdkafka: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with module API=20210902
>
> PHP    compiled with module API=20190902
>
> These options need to match

I assume that maybe my rdkafka module is to recent for this PHP binary, and I tried to install older version by doing ->

```
sudo pecl uninstall rdkafka && sudo pecl install rdkafka-4.0.0
```

According to pecl.php.net website, this version is the closest to my PHP binary compiled module ( https://pecl.php.net/package/rdkafka )

However there is an error while compiling the source code of this version.

> make: *** [Makefile:205: rdkafka.lo] Error 1

I also tried several solutions proposed on various sources but I can not figure out how to make it work, and I havnt used PHP for like 10 years so my knowledge are very bad.

Anyone know how to fix or can give me some lead ?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the problem, instead of looking for a older version of this kafka module ( which does not compile on my system ), I tried with a newer version of PHP ( 8.1 ) and it run perfectly. Luckily for me it is compatible with my code base

Answer (score 0):

I am using xampp php version 7.4 on windows and got the same error .
In my case commenting out the extension in php.ini for lib sodium did the trick.

```
extension=php_sodium.dll
```